# SQL Query not Grouping Correctly

Tags: sql

I have written a query that is meant to sum up rows which have the same ID and technically this will be done by grouping but for some reason mine isn't working. I may be missing something obvious but not too sure. For example if they have the same `id` column or `clientid` either is fine then group and sum the total cost columns

```
select
    CD.id as clientId, CD.name, CD.brandName, q.CreatedTime, q.id ,

case when sum((P.cost + P.baggingCost + p.deliveryCost + p.additionalCost + p.markupCost)*po.quantity) is null then 0 

else 

case when P.FixedCost = 1 then

sum((P.cost + P.baggingCost + p.deliveryCost + p.additionalCost + p.markupCost)*po.quantity)

else

sum((P.cost + P.baggingCost + p.deliveryCost + p.additionalCost)* (1+(cast(p.markupCost as money)/100))*po.quantity)

end

end as TotalCost, po.cpqStatus
from
    [dbo].[quote] Q
    join [dbo].[clientDetails] CD on Q.cpqClientContactId = CD.id
    join [dbo].[productsOrdered] PO on PO.quoteId = Q.id
    join [dbo].[products] P on pO.productId = P.id
where po.cpqStatus != 3
group by CD.id, CD.name, CD.brandName, q.CreatedTime, q.id, po.cpqStatus, P.FixedCost
```

Currently this is producing:

[image]

Comment: can you add column in your result of  `P.FixedCost` it's 0 and 1 in 447 id.

Comment: @PiyushKachhadiya Ah you're right, FixedCost is 0 and 1 for 447; how would I ignore this value and just group based on id?

Comment: use case when in `sum()` and remove from group by.